# efficient way to do nested for loop and add to list

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

Below I have written some code that works and prints the right result, but is there a much more efficient way to do this using nested for loops, instead of having 5 different for loops?

```
String A = "";
String B = "";
String C  = "";
String D  = "";
String E  = "";

ArrayList<String> id = new ArrayList<String>();

int row = 5;
for (int i=0; i < row; i++) {
    A = "id0"+i;
    id.add(A);
}
for (int i=0; i < row; i++) {
    B = "id1"+i;
    id.add(B);
}
for (int i=0; i < row; i++) {
    C = "id2"+i;
    id.add(C);
}
for (int i=0; i < row; i++) {
    D = "id3"+i;
    id.add(D);
}
for (int i=0; i < row; i++) {
    E = "id4"+i;
    id.add(E);
}
return id;
```

result
`[id00, id01, id02, id03, id04, id10, id11, id12, id13, id14, id20, id21, id22, id23, id24, id30, id31, id32, id33, id34, id40, id41, id42, id43, id44]`

Comment: 5 loops which you are creating is it fixed or dynamic

Comment: *Is there a much more efficient way to do this using nested for loops, instead of having 5 different for loops?* - Yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should produce the same output by using a nested loop

```
ArrayList<String> id = new ArrayList<>();
int row = 5;
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < row; j++) {
        id.add("id" + i + j);
    }
}
return id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```
ArrayList<String> id = new ArrayList<String>();
int row=5;
for (int i=0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j < row; j++) {
        String temp = "id" + i + j;
        id.add(temp);
    }
}
```

This simplifies the code into 2 nested for loops, with a single string variable instead of 5. This also shouldn't change the time complexity of your solution since the outer loop is constant.